# Binomial coefficient identity ${n \choose 2} + n = {n + 1 \choose 2}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I can see why this is true using Pascal's triangle or the recurrence relation, but algebraically there must be a way and I'm just missing something (trying to sort out factorials using the binomial coefficient formula didn't work out for me).

${n \choose 2} + n = {n + 1 \choose 2}$

Comment: it's not true:  $$\binom20+2\ne\binom30$$

Comment: massive typo, thanks!

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$${n \choose 2} + n = {n + 1 \choose 2}$$

is just

$$\dfrac{n(n-1)}2+n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$$

Comment: thanks! i kept confusing myself with the $(n-2)!$ divisor, forgetting that it is effectively just truncating the factorial in the numerator.

Answer (score 3):

The correct identity is
$$
\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}.
$$
To prove it, observe that
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n-k}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \binom{n}{k+1}=\frac{k+1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}.
$$
Add together these two equations to get the result.